# JSP, MYSQL Left Join not showing results

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have two tables in db. Buyers and Games

```
CREATE TABLE `buyers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=236 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `games` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `buyer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `game_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `nalog` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nab_cena` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `prod_cena` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `kupci_id_idx` (`buyer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `buyer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`buyer_id`) REFERENCES `buyers` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=362 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

They are connected by buyers.id = games.buyer_id

Buyers table with records
[Buyers Table with records][1]

Games table with records
[Games table with records][2]

When I do query in MySQL dashboard with left join to find all games that buyer bought so far I am able to get result

MySQL query

```
select buyers.fname, games.game_name as 'Game Name', games.email
from buyers
left join games on games.buyer_id=buyers.id
where buyers.id=225;
```

I am getting correct result

[correct result][3]

But when I do same in my JSP page I am not getting any result. Connection to database is good, there are other jsp pages for select all buyers or select all games that are working good.

Here is code of JSP page

```
<%                    

                    Connection connection = null;
                    Statement statement = null;
                    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
                    ResultSet resultSet = null;
                    String id = request.getParameter("id");
                    try {
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl + database, userid, password);

                        String sql = "select buyers.fname, games.game_name, games.email"
                                + "from buyers"
                                + "left join games on games.buyer_id=buyers.id"
                                + "where buyers.id=?";
                        pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                        pstmt.setString(1, id);
                        resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
                        while (resultSet.next()) {
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("buyers.fname")%></td>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("games.game_name")%></td>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("games.email")%></td>
                </tr>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DxRW.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/26k1S.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/orD9d.jpg
```

Comment: Does this say 'emailfrom' and 'buyersleft' and 'buyers.idwhere'?

Comment: "select buyers.fname, games.game_name, games.email"
                                + "from buyers"
                                + "left   join   games   on   games.buyer_id  =   buyers.id"
                                + "where   buyers.id  =  ?  " ;
                        

                        pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                        pstmt.setString(1, id);
                        resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
                        while (resultSet.next()) {

Comment: Yes, i don't know jsp but it looks to me like you're missing some spaces.